# Accessing kubernetes service host content in local web browser

Tags: http, kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-service

I have a service on my kubernetes cluster:

```
root@nginx-helloworld:/usr/share/nginx/html/docker# kubectl describe service tb-broker
Name:                     tb-broker
Namespace:                thingsboard-mqtt-broker
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=tb-broker
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.107.211.8
IPs:                      10.107.211.8
External IPs:             192.168.4.4
Port:                     http  8083/TCP
TargetPort:               8083/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30001/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.3.8:8083,192.168.6.14:8083
Port:                     mqtt-tcp  1883/TCP
TargetPort:               1883/TCP
NodePort:                 mqtt-tcp  30002/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.3.8:1883,192.168.6.14:1883
Port:                     mqtt-ssl  8883/TCP
TargetPort:               8883/TCP
NodePort:                 mqtt-ssl  30003/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.3.8:8883,192.168.6.14:8883
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I setup external IP for this service by command:

```
kubectl patch svc tb-broker -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.4.4"]}}'
```

I want to access the web interface in my local web browser.
How can I do that? I failed with: `192.168.4.4:30001`, `10.107.211.8:30001` and any other possibility. What should I do more for making this happen?